# how to place the default text in the <textarea>

Tags: html

i am try to place the default text in the textarea using the 'value' property.But it is not working. please give me some solution for this.

Comment: You should be more specific. What is not working and how exactly it is not working?

Comment: Also, you do not accept people answers. I don't think someone will want to help you.

Comment: @FractalizeR: Normally, i'd agree about being more specific.  But in this case, the problem is clear to people who work with HTML (particularly forms) on a regular basis.

Answer (score 5):

here it is ..

```
<textarea> default value here </textarea>
```

from the [w3 on textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7)

> The TEXTAREA element creates a multi-line text input control. User agents should use **the contents of this element as the initial value of the control and should render this text initially**.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
<textarea>Default Text...</textarea>
```

It has not `value` property. You should put default text in between opening and closing tags.

[Here is the W3C Specification for `textarea`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7)

```
<!ATTLIST TEXTAREA
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED
  rows        NUMBER         #REQUIRED
  cols        NUMBER         #REQUIRED
  disabled    (disabled)     #IMPLIED  -- unavailable in this context --
  readonly    (readonly)     #IMPLIED
  tabindex    NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- position in tabbing order --
  accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED  -- accessibility key character --
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element got the focus --
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element lost the focus --
  onselect    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- some text was selected --
  onchange    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element value was changed --
  >
```

Answer (score 3):

For textarea elements, the default value goes between the tags.  Like so:

```
<textarea name="bigtext">This is the text that will appear in the box.</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide it in the tag content instead:

```
<textarea>Default text</textarea>
```

To get or set the text using JavaScript, you will need to access the `textContent` or `innerText` properties:

```
if ("textContent" in myTextArea)
    alert(myTextArea.textContent);
else 
    alert(myTextArea.innerText);
```